# MS SQL statement using PARTIAL and DISTINCT in VB.NET

Tags: distinct, partial

I have a table called `Postcodes` which has over half a million records.
Inside this table i have a column called `PostCodeText` which has the following:

```
NG1 1AA
NG1 1AB
NG1 1AC
NG2 1AA
NG2 5TH
NG17 3LP
DE15 4BP
NG17 5GL
DE19 4EE...
```

What I need is a MSSQL statement that return `DISTINCT` matches based on a partial string. For example: If I wanted to find all distinct NG postcodes I would want to return:

```
NG1
NG2
NG17
```

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT postcodetext 
FROM postcodes 
WHERE (postcode_text LIKE 'NG%') 
ORDER BY postcodetext
```

I feel I might be close to the answer but its not there yet, any help would be much appricated. 
Also I heard that using `LIKE` is a slower option then using `=` is there a faster way then doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
SELECT LEFT(postcodetext,CHARINDEX(' ',postcodetext,0))
FROM postcodes
WHERE postcodetext like 'NG%'
GROUP BY LEFT(postcodetext,CHARINDEX(' ',postcodetext,0))
ORDER BY postcodetext
```

OK, I think I'm missing something here, the above statement work fine (if I drop the `ORDER BY`), when I run it in management studio. But when I run it in my VB.net code I'm having an issue:

After running the statement and assigning the values into my datatable, I then use the following code :

```vb
For Each rows In dt.Rows
    Select Case opt
        Case 1 ' 
            frmSettings.lstAllPostcodes.Items.Add(rows.Item("postcodetext"))
            frmSettings.ProgBarSettings.Value = i
            i = i + 1
    End Select
Next
```

It fails when trying to reference `rows.item("postcodetext")`. I realise that has something to do with the `SELECT` statement using the `LEFT` of. I would like my listbox to hold the partial results (ie `NG1`, `NG2`, `NG17` etc etc)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply but that statement give me the error message "Column "postcodes.postcodetext" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." : Not sure what this means?

Comment: If i drop the ORDER BY it works! Thanks, but would be nice to Order by in the SQL statement rather then later via code, but it works for now so thank you very much!